# UML: What does this relationship mean?

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I started to generate UML class diagrams from an existing Java project in Netbeans IDE, when I came across this symbol (see image).
What does it mean?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I would like to see the whole picture. HTH http://netbeans.org/download/magazine/02/nb02-part7-uml.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A circle at the end of a UML relationship most times shows Ownership. The entity at the dotted end us owned by the entity without the dot. In your example, `SynchronizationResult` owns whatever entity has `internalCOmmandReceived` defined on it.

Normally, these dots are shaded opaque. But seeing that this was generated using Netbeans, this may be their way of depicting the same thing.

EDIT:
I may have had those reversed. Under IBM's explaination of [the basics of UML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/), this symbol is used to show ***membership***. If you scroll to the *Packages* aspect of the guide (Section 9), you will see the explanation

Hope this helps. And sorry for the mixup earlier.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. The class SessionCommandProcessor contains an inner class called SynchronizationResult.

Comment: Oh cool. I just needed to get my facts right and have a source. glad it helped clarify things